# Asymptotic Expansion of Bessel $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{x\cos t}dt$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

My question is how to find the asmyptotic expansion of $I(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{x\cos t}dt$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

I already got the expansion of $\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-x\sin^2t} dt$ by using the substitution $\sin^2 t=u$ but how are they connected?

Comment: I thing $1-2\sin^2t = \cos 2t$ might help you get to the cosine you are looking for.

Comment: I was thinking of the same substitution but I did not come forward, it would be helpful if you could go into little more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-x\sin^2t} dt = \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-x\cdot\frac{1-\cos 2t}{2}} dt= e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{\frac{x}{2}\cos 2t}dt = \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{2} \int_0^{\pi}e^{\frac{x}{2}\cos u}du = \frac{\pi e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{2} I(\tfrac{x}{2})
$$
I think...

Comment: I think the $\pi$ crosses out in the last part. Yes this solves my problem indeed